# Select by two values (AND), and if nothing will be found select by each (OR)

Tags: php, mysql

I have MYSQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE ";
if ($city) { $where .= ($where ? " AND " : "")." ( city = '$city' ) "; }
if ($street) { $where .= ($where ? " AND " : "")."( street = '$street'"); }

if ($where) { 
  $sql .= $where;             
  $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($dbconnect_finder)); 
}
```

I would like to build up this query, that if nothing will be found, it will use OR operator instead of AND. I know I can do query again, if there will be no resoults. To reduce costs, I would like to do it in one query.

EDIT:
When user will search for $city and $street, and will use $city = "Londan" (insteed of London), $street = "someStreet". AND operator will not work. Then OR operator should work. Is it possible to do it in one MYSQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = '$city' OR street = '$street'";
```

Or even you can try with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = '$city'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(count($result) == 0) {
   $sql .= " OR street = '$street'"; 
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

And since `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated** you better use `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` statements.

Comment: I can't use OR operator form the beggining. Because if user will write: $city: "London", $street: "someStreet", it will select streets outside London. I want to do this, but only if $city AND $street not working together.

Comment: Yes this answer is good, but to reduce costs I would like to do it in one query.

Comment: @user3021198 may the second ans will help you

Comment: There is two mysql_queries, I would like to do it in one :) Because code is even more complicated, it is searching by post code, house number etc. I had to have like 30 queries then :]

Answer (score 0):

TRy executing this code, i have made use of a varibale named cityPresent , so if that is true you AND it, else you OR it/

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE ";
$cityPresent = false;
if ($city) { $where .= ($where ? " AND " : "")." ( city = '$city' ) "; $cityPresent = true; }
if ($street && $cityPresent) { $where .= ($where ? " AND " : "")."( street = '$street'"); }
else { $where .= ($where ? " OR " : "")."( street = '$street'"); }


if ($where) { 
  $sql .= $where;             
  $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($dbconnect_finder)); 
}
```

Comment: It is about wrong string. When user will write: $city = "Londun", $street = "somestreet". It won't find place using AND operator. Then I would like MYSQL to use OR. I know how to do it in PHP using two queries, but mby you have an idea how to do it in one MYSQL query?

Comment: Well in that case you are better of implementing a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I hope this be useful:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE ";
if (isset($where)) { 
  if (isset($city)) {
    $where .= " AND '$city'";
  }
  if (isset($street)) { 
    $where .= " AND '$street'";
  }
  $sql .= $where;
} 

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($dbconnect_finder));
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. It is about wrong string, not about string presence.

Comment: What is wrong string? Can you give me a wrong and a true string?

Comment: It's just my shortcut. String that doesn't presence in DB. It's "Londun" insteed of "London".